# Cocoa Autolayout: content hugging vs content compression resistance priority

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I can't find a clear answer on Apple documentation regarding Cocoa Autolayout about the difference between content hugging and compression resistance.

Can somebody explain their usages and difference ?

Comment: One of life's major mysterious is why they didn't call it simply "Expansion Resistance".  The two qualities are nothing more than **"Expansion Resistance" and "Compression Resistance"**.  The "hugging" terminology is insane.

Comment: **If** you have too much room then `content-hugging`: would fight against having white space . It would just force the view to get around you. But **if** you don't have too much space, and instead have very little place then `content-compressions-resistance` would fight against your view from not being able to show all its content, e.g. labels would get truncated.

Answer (score 1419, accepted):

A quick summary of the concepts:

- Hugging => content does not want to grow
- Compression Resistance => content does not want to shrink

Example:

Say you've got a button like this:

```
[       Click Me      ]
```

and you've pinned the edges to a larger superview with priority 500.

Then, if Hugging priority > 500 it'll look like this:

```
[Click Me]
```

If Hugging priority < 500 it'll look like this:

```
[       Click Me      ]
```

If the superview now shrinks then, if the Compression Resistance priority > 500, it'll look like this

```
[Click Me]
```

Else if Compression Resistance priority < 500,  it could look like this:

```
[Cli..]
```

If it doesn't work like this then you've probably got some other constraints going on that are messing up your good work!

E.g. you could have it pinned to the superview with priority 1000.
Or you could have a width priority. If so, this can be helpful:

Editor > Size to Fit Content

Comment: What if hugging priority == 500?

Comment: I'd *assume* (but that's usually not a good idea) it'd be treated as >500 like typical rounding behavior. Haven't tested that though.

Comment: most likely you'll get "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" warning in runtime

Comment: @bradley.ayers To MaxDesyatov's comment, that will only happen if you have conflicting constraints with Required priority (1000). If two lower-priority constraints conflict, the solution is ambiguous so the Auto Layout engine will just pick one valid solution and that's what you'll see (no warnings). Obviously this isn't good, because it's now up to the internal implementation of the Auto Layout engine to choose how your layout looks, and theoretically this could change from one iOS version to the next!

Comment: The content hugging priority default is 250, and the content compression resistance default is 750. So why use 500?

Comment: The priorities are relative to others' priorities.   And if all sub-views' constraints priorities are the same, it will be evaluated from left to right, or conforming to constraints' options. @bradley.ayers

Comment: I have a question, " you've pinned the edges to a larger superview with priority 500. " , which one of the superview's priority take effect with the subview's hugging priority, hugging priority or compression priority?

Comment: Apple could have used "Expansion Resistance (or similar)" word instead of "Hugging". "Hugging" is too much confusing and irrelevant word with "Compression Resistance" in my opinion.

Comment: example, the label we don't want shrinking, again, is the title label since the description label can be truncated if need be. To ensure our title label doesn't truncate its contents, we want to make sure its compression resistance priority is higher than our description label's compression resistance.

Comment: Would it be correct to say: you no longer need to set the width/height and just set the leading, top constraints and then allow the intrinsic content size to kick in all while you also set your content hugging/content resistance?

Comment: This is the best answer on the internet. I keep coming back to this answer when I run into problems with this, Even after a 10+ years of iOS development.

Answer (score 318):

Take a look at this video [tutorial about Autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout), they explain it carefully

[image]

Comment: @fatuhoku can you check again, this video is free

Comment: Hugging vs. Resistance discussion starts at about the 13:15 point in the video.

Comment: @onmyway133 this is perfect video, but unfortunately there is no example how Ray uses it.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander I think a very practical example would be Dynamic cell height with Autolayout http://www.fantageek.com/1468/ios-dynamic-table-view-cells-with-varying-row-height-and-autolayout/

Comment: If I want a parent view expand or shrink with sub views, how should I do with these 2 situations?

Comment: Yeah this was the point missing in accepted answer that if there are 2 or more uiviews then their CHCR priorties works in comparison to each-others priority numbers. Good Detail here: https://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real

Comment: He shows how to use the compression resistance at 18:05

Comment: so if an image has a lower content compression resistance...it will be scaled...to something smaller . But from what I see in your answer, the label (w/ lower content compression resistance), it won't be rescaled to a smaller font...rather the label would get truncated. Is there any way to make the label resize itself? or I guess that's normally not a good idea?

Comment: It really helped to understand.

Answer (score 289):

[image]

source: [@mokagio](https://twitter.com/mokagio)

**Intrinsic Content Size** - Pretty self-explanatory, but views with variable content are aware of how big their content is and describe their content's size through this property. Some obvious examples of views that have intrinsic content sizes are UIImageViews, UILabels, UIButtons.

**Content Hugging Priority** - The higher this priority is, the more a view resists growing larger than its intrinsic content size.

**Content Compression Resistance Priority** - The higher this priority is, the more a view resists shrinking smaller than its intrinsic content size.

Check here for more explanation: [AUTO LAYOUT MAGIC: CONTENT SIZING PRIORITIES](https://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real)

Comment: The illustration is nice but misleading to say the least. The top guy should say "I'm not gonna (let ME) grow". The child view defines on its own that it doesn't want to grow through it's content hugging behavior. There is no exogenic force (like the illustrated hands) that stop it from growing. That is a big difference.

Comment: I'm up voting this just because I love the illustration.

Comment: This is why I love Stack Overflow… Snowcrash's description plus this illustration by mokagio = best explanation of these properties anywhere (including Apple's own documentation).

Comment: @Manuel I don't think it's child view and parent view here. Rather the rectangle is the view and the person is the implicitly generated system constraint trying to achieve the desired behaviour (hugging or compression resistance) with set priority. So the illustration is still right.

Answer (score 45):

Let's say you have a button with the text, "Click Me". What width should that button be?

First, you definitely don't want the button to be smaller than the text. Otherwise, the text would be clipped. This is the horizontal compression resistance priority.

Second, you don't want the button to be bigger than it needs to be. A button that looked like this, [          Click Me          ], is obviously too big. You want the button to "hug" its contents without too much padding. This is the horizontal content hugging priority. For a button, it isn't as strong as the horizontal compression resistance priority.

Answer (score 21):

If `view.intrinsicContentSize.width != NSViewNoIntrinsicMetric`, then auto layout creates a special constraint of type `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint`. This constraint acts like **two** normal constraints:

- a constraint requiring `view.width <= view.intrinsicContentSize.width` with the horizontal hugging priority, and
- a constraint requiring `view.width >= view.intrinsicContentSize.width` with the horizontal compression resistance priority.

In Swift, with iOS 9's new layout anchors, you could set up equivalent constraints like this:

```swift
let horizontalHugging = view.widthAnchor.constraint(
    lessThanOrEqualToConstant: view.intrinsicContentSize.width)
horizontalHugging.priority = view.contentHuggingPriority(for: .horizontal)

let horizontalCompression = view.widthAnchor.constraint(
    greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: view.intrinsicContentSize.width)
horizontalCompression.priority = view.contentCompressionResistancePriority(for: .horizontal)
```

Similarly, if `view.intrinsicContentSize.height != NSViewNoIntrinsicMetric`, then auto layout creates an `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint` that acts like two constraints on the view's height. In code, they would look like this:

```
let verticalHugging = view.heightAnchor.constraint(
    lessThanOrEqualToConstant: view.intrinsicContentSize.height)
verticalHugging.priority = view.contentHuggingPriority(for: .vertical)

let verticalCompression = view.heightAnchor.constraint(
    greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: view.intrinsicContentSize.height)
verticalCompression.priority = view.contentCompressionResistancePriority(for: .vertical)
```

You can see these special `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint` instances (if they exist) by printing `view.constraints` after layout has run. Example:

```
label.constraints.forEach { print($0) }

// Output:
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7fd82982af90 H:[UILabel:0x7fd82980e5e0'Hello'(39)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7fd82982b4f0 V:[UILabel:0x7fd82980e5e0'Hello'(21)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>
```

Comment: should it not be: let verticalCompression = view.heightAnchor.constraint(
    greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: view.intrinsicContentSize.height)

Comment: Yes, I made a copy/paste error. I have corrected it. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 15):

Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistence Priorities work for elements which can calculate their size intrinsically depending upon the contents which are coming in.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1):

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. For a textView that doesn't have scrolling enabled. Does that mean per user typing the intrinsic size would change?

Comment: @Honey I think with correct constraints set and scrolling disabled, text view should be able to tell intrinsic height.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. You mean if I type a lot a lot, more than the current size of the textView....does the textView expand automatically and change the intrinsic size?

Comment: Try it yourself. Give textview a fixed width and disable the scroll and check for desired behaviour. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21287306/1526629 for more answers.

Answer (score 15):

The **`Content hugging priority`** is like a ***Rubber band*** that is placed around a view. 
The higher the priority value, the stronger the rubber band and the more it wants to hug to its content size.
The priority value can be imagined like the "strength" of the rubber band

And the **`Content Compression Resistance`** is, how much a ***view "resists" getting smaller*** 
The View with higher resistance priority value is the one that will resist compression.

Answer (score 0):

***contentCompressionResistancePriority*** – The view with the lowest value gets truncated when there is not enough space to fit everything’s `intrinsicContentSize`

***contentHuggingPriority*** – The view with the lowest value gets expanded beyond its `intrinsicContentSize` when there is leftover space to fill

Comment: I always remember this now and ever since have had no issues. Resistance priority is important when there is not enough space to fit elements. Hugging priority is important when there is too much space.

Answer (score 0):

When we thinking about these two priorities, we need to consider the conditions.

When the space is **enough for two or more widgets**, we consider `hugging priority`, the priority is less, it will take the surplus space, and other widgets only take the Intrinsic Content Size.

When the space is **not enough for widgets**, we consider the `Content Compression Resistance` as well.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS AutoLayout - Intrinsic Content Size And Content Hugging & Content Compression Resistence Priority(CHCR)**

[[AutoLayout]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70213665/4770877)

**Intrinsic Content Size**

```
Intrinsic Content Size -> Constraint -> AutoLayout engine -> draw
```

`AutoLayout` uses `Intrinsic Content Size` to create implicit constraint(width and/or height)

Intrinsic Content Size - tells how much space(width and/or height) is needed to show a **full** content.

- [Official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1) says

> Not all views have an intrinsic content size

> UIView and NSView - No intrinsic content size

- But actually - `UIView` **object** doesn't have it and `UIView` **class** has `intrinsicContentSize` variable which is/can be overrode by subclass. For example `UILabel` has it's own realization which is based on text and font attributes
- `UIView` subclass uses default realisation with [UIView.noIntrinsicMetric](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622486-nointrinsicmetric) (-1)

pseudocode:

```
import UIKit

class UIView {
   override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric)
   }
}
```

- when you need to recalculate `intrinsicContentSize` and redraw it - call `view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`
- `intrinsicContentSize` vs `sizeToFit()`. `intrinsicContentSize` is for AutoLayout, `sizeToFit()` is for Frame-based.

  - call `view.sizeToFit()`
  - override `view.sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize)`. size usually is view.bounds.size

[[iOS intrinsicContentSize]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73662705/4770877)

**Content Hugging & Content Compression Resistence Priority(CHCR)**

Every view has a CHCR priority for each dimension(horizontal, vertical) but it is applied only view with `intrinsicContentSize`. Also it has an impact on constraint priority

**Content Hugging Priority(CHP)(default value is 251)**

Prevent expanding. Higher priority - prevent view to be bigger then Intrinsic Content Size.

**Content Compression Resistence Priority(CRP)(default value is 750)**

Prevent collapsing. Higher priority - prevent view to be smaller then Intrinsic Content Size.

Experiments:

Two UILabels(Label 1, Label 2), which is layout one by one horizontally

1. Warning:

```
Content Priority Ambiguity
Decrease horizontal hugging...
```

[image]

2. To fix it using Content Hugging Priority

[image]

3. Warning:

```
Content Priority Ambiguity
Decrease horizontal compression resistance...
```

[image]

4. To fix it using Content Compression Resistence Priority

[image]

5. If you want to show both Labels you can use width constraint which has bigger priority(1000 by default)

[image]