# Toolbar not filling the whole width at iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode5, uitoolbar

I am reading (through O'Reilly Safari) the book [Learning iPad Programming](http://www.learningipadprogramming.com/) and there is a modal view with a toolbar and 2 buttons ("Cancel" and "Done") at the top.

My problem is that when I try to recreate that universal app, at the iPad simulator the toolbar doesn't use the whole window width:

[image]

There is a "flexible space" element between the buttons, but it seems not to affect the parent toolbar.

Can anybody please advise me how to stretch the toolbar and the textfield, maybe I need to set some property of it in Xcode 5?

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I've attached 2 new screenshots - don't see any "autoresizing" in Xcode 5:

[image]

[image]

I've submitted my question [at Github](https://github.com/kirbyt/PhotoWheel/issues/3) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Looks like your View doesn't resize to the complete width. I guess it does not have the Autoresizing Width attribute. You can set in in InterfaceBuilder of your xib in the size inspector.

[image: size inspector xib]

Comment: Could you make the same screenshots (Attributes and Size inspector) without selecting toolbar but only View.

Comment: I've updated my question with the requested screenshot (Xcode 5, View selected) - unfortunately do not see any Autosizing there. There is only Origin.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Try reducing the content hugging priority of the view to 1 and check the behavior. You may need also to add constraint to the toolbar and reduce hugging priority to allow it to grow.

Comment: Adding constraints (as an iOS newbie I didn't know about them) has helped me, thanks. The book author has recommended them too: https://github.com/kirbyt/PhotoWheel/issues/3  What's a "hugging priority"? :-)

Comment: See this for quick explanation on hugging priority and compression resistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority