# How do I set iOS constraints for 4 text boxes to scale horizontally when I rotate?

Tags: ios, textbox, view, constraints

I have four text boxes positioned like this on my view:

|----| |--------|   |----| |---------|

As you can see, the first in each group is one width and the second is a different width (but equal to each other).

I've placed these on my view in landscape orientation.  What I want to happen is have all four scale down when I rotate to portrait orientation.

I've tried constraining every which way I can think of and the closest I can come to getting it to work is having the two on the left stay the same size and the two on the right squish up.

i.e.

|----| |--------|  |--| |----|

What I really need is for all four to squish up equally like this:

|---| |------|  |---| |------|

How can I set the constraints in my storyboard so that it works?  (Please note:  I do not want to do this in code as the view I'm building is a very detailed form-like page and will have a ton of text boxes on it--I don't want to code that much.)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting minimum widths on each button? Also look into content hugging and compression resistance (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority)

Comment: I found a solution.  What I did was select all four boxes and set left and right constraints.  Then I selected box #1 and box #3 (from left to right) and set "Equal Widths" constraints.  Then I selected box #2 and box #4 and set "Equal Widths" constraints.  I probably overdid something, but this worked.

Comment: Also, thanks for the other article link Kyle C.  Very good stuff.