# What is the content compression resistance and content hugging of a UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

What is the content compression resistance and content hugging of a UIView? How do these relate to the intrinsic content size of a view?

Comment: If you're looking for the specific values, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924093/what-are-the-default-auto-layout-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resista.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority) Check the above link , explained in a very simple manner

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Taken from [objc.io](http://www.objc.io)'s excellent [Advanced Auto Layout Toolbox article](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html):

> **Intrinsic Content Size**
>
> The intrinsic content size is the size a view prefers to have for a specific content it displays. For example, UILabel has a preferred height based on the font, and a preferred width based on the font and the text it displays. A UIProgressView only has a preferred height based on its artwork, but no preferred width. A plain UIView has neither a preferred width nor a preferred height.
>
> **Compression Resistance and Content Hugging**
>
> Each view has content
>   compression resistance priorities and content hugging priorities
>   assigned for both dimensions. These properties only take effect for
>   views which define an intrinsic content size, otherwise there is no
>   content size defined that could resist compression or be hugged.
>
> Behind the scenes, the intrinsic content size and these priority
>   values get translated into constraints. For a label with an intrinsic
>   content size of { 100, 30 }, horizontal/vertical compression
>   resistance priority of 750, and horizontal/vertical content hugging
>   priority of 250, four constraints will be generated:
>
> ```
> H:[label(<=100@250)] 
> H:[label(>=100@750)]
> V:[label(<=30@250)]
> V:[label(>=30@750)]
> ```
>
> If you’re not familiar with the visual format language for the
>   constraints used above, you can read up about it in Apple’s
>   documentation. Keeping in mind that these additional constraints are
>   generated implicitly helps to understand Auto Layout’s behavior and to
>   make better sense of its error messages.

Here's another StackOverflow question that addresses the difference between content compression resistance & content hugging:
[Cocoa Autolayout: content hugging vs content compression resistance priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority)