# What are the default Auto Layout Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance priority values?

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm trying to debug an Auto Layout problem, and knowing the default values for Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance priorities will help.

What are they? Are they specific to particular components? Are there constants I can use to refer to them?

Keywords: UILayoutPriority

Answer (score 74, accepted):

These values are up-to-date as of Xcode 7.3.

---

## Interface Builder Default Priority Values:

When dragging a component into Interface Builder, you get the following priorities. Note: `(250,750)` stands for `250` horizontal, and `750` vertical.

```
+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
|         Object          | Hugging (H,V) | Compression Resistance (H,V) |
+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
| UIActivityIndicatorView | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIButton                | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIDatePicker            | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIImageView             | 251,251       | 750,750                      |
| UILabel                 | 251,251       | 750,750                      |
| UIPageControl           | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIPickerView            | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIProgressView          | 250,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIScrollView            | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UISearchBar             | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UISegmentedControl      | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UISlider                | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIStepper               | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UISwitch                | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UITabBar                | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UITextField             | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UITextView              | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIToolbar               | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIView                  | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
```

Findings:

- All objects have `750,750` as their **Content Compression Resistance Priority**.
- The majority have `250,250` as their **Content Hugging Priority**.
- `UIImageView` and `UILabel` both have `251,251` as their **Content Hugging Priority**.
- `UIActivityIndicatorView`, `UIStepper`, and `UISwitch` have `750,750` as their **Content Hugging Priority**.
- `UIProgressView` has `250,750` as its **Content Hugging Priority**.

---

## Programmatic Default Priority Values:

When creating an object programmatically (e.g. `UIButton()`), you get the following priorities.

```
+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
|         Object          | Hugging (H,V) | Compression Resistance (H,V) |
+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
| UIActivityIndicatorView | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIButton                | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIDatePicker            | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIImageView             | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UILabel                 | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIPageControl           | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIPickerView            | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIProgressView          | 250,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIScrollView            | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UISearchBar             | 250,750       | 750,750                      |
| UISegmentedControl      | 250,750       | 750,750                      |
| UISlider                | 250,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIStepper               | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UISwitch                | 750,750       | 750,750                      |
| UITabBar                | 250,750       | 750,750                      |
| UITextField             | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UITextView              | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
| UIToolbar               | 250,750       | 750,750                      |
| UIView                  | 250,250       | 750,750                      |
+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
```

Findings:

- There are **Content Hugging Priority** differences between IB instantiated objects and programmatically instantiated objects for the following objects: UIDatePicker, UIImageView, UILabel, UIPageControl, UIPickerView, UISearchBar, UISegmentedControl, UISlider, UITabBar, and UIToolbar.

---

## Programmatic Constants

```
+----------------------------------+-------+
|             Constant             | Value |
+----------------------------------+-------+
| UILayoutPriorityRequired         |  1000 |
| UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh      |   750 |
| UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow       |   250 |
| UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel |    50 |
+----------------------------------+-------+
```

---

When you add a constraint (either via Interface Builder or programmatically), its default priority is `1000`.

Comment: This is super useful, can't believe Apple hasn't documented this, especially the differences between IB and in-code initialized objects

Comment: Does UIStackView has priority?