# Why is this layout ambiguous?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a basic cell with some labels and an image view. Im adding constraints using the visual format language, but at runtime they turn out to be ambiguous. What is going on?!

```
[self.constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[_typeLabel]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_typeLabel)]];
[self.constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[_addressLabel]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_addressLabel)]];
[self.constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[_mapImageView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mapImageView)]];
[self.constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-11-[_typeLabel]-2-[_addressLabel]-[_mapImageView]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_typeLabel, _addressLabel, _mapImageView)]];
```

**Here is my _autolayoutTrace:**

```
*<UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30>
|   *<UILabel:0x943aab0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   *<UILabel:0x940ead0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   *<UIImageView:0x9445c20> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView:0x9446200>
```

**And here are the constraints affecting the first two UILabels:**

```
(lldb) po [0x943aab0 constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:0]
<__NSArrayM 0x975fee0>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x940eca0 H:|-(15)-[UILabel:0x943aab0]   (Names:'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x940ecf0 H:[UILabel:0x943aab0]-(10)-|   (Names:'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x9446a70 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30(320)]>
)


(lldb) po [0x943aab0 constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:1]
<__NSArrayM 0xaa4af10>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9446030 V:|-(11)-[UILabel:0x943aab0]   (Names:'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30 )>,
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x943a840 V:[UILabel:0x943aab0(17)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>
)


(lldb) po [0x940ead0 constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:0]
<__NSArrayM 0x97b4240>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x940ed90 H:|-(15)-[UILabel:0x940ead0]   (Names:'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x940ede0 H:[UILabel:0x940ead0]-(10)-|   (Names:'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30 )>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x9446a70 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30(320)]>
)


(lldb) po [0x940ead0 constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:1]
<__NSArrayM 0xa985d30>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9446030 V:|-(11)-[UILabel:0x943aab0]   (Names:'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x940dc30 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9446080 V:[UILabel:0x943aab0]-(2)-[UILabel:0x940ead0]>,
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x943a840 V:[UILabel:0x943aab0(17)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>,
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x9446bb0 V:[UILabel:0x940ead0(33)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ambiguous layout you need to set to properties of lables like `contentHugging` and `contentCompressionResistance`

Hope will help you

**Edit:** for learning about this properties you can follow 
[Cocoa Autolayout: content hugging vs content compression resistance priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority/16281229#16281229)