# Equal width and equal spacing between buttons in autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to use autolayout constraints to automatically resize a few similarly-sized buttons in a view to give the following effect:

**Before resizing**

[image: Before stretching]

**Desired effect after resizing**

[image: After stretching]

As you can tell, I want the buttons to be of the same size and I also want the spacing between each button to be a constant 20 points. It seems pretty simple at first, so I set the following constraints:

- Buttons: space from left neighbour = 20 (inclusive of left-most and right-most buttons)
- Buttons: space from right neighbour = 20 (inclusive of left-most and right-most buttons)
- Buttons: same width

**What actually happens after resizing**

[image]

When in preview or when I test run the app in my iPhone/simulator, the button resizes and doesn't even follow the same width constraint I set for it. In fact, the view containing the views also resizes to fit the new button sizes. Anyone knows how to fix this problem purely in the interface builder?

Comment: did you achieve adding "20" pixels space as given above? can u share something regarding the same?

Comment: @Jeev Yes I did by redoing everything. Unfortunately I was unable to find out what I did incorrectly, hence I didn't post an answer. The 3 points above is enough to satisfy the constraints.

Comment: From the look of it you probably had content compression resistance priority not smaller than the equal widths constraints' priority

Comment: @DavideDeFranceschi I don't think so. I remember I did not meddle with any content hugging/compression priority when I got the error the last time and when I successfully did it.

Comment: I had the same issue. tip: it was very revealing to put a border on the buttons. the actual size of the buttons were bigger than I thought.     func makeButtonsPretty() {
        
        for element in buttons {
            element.layer.borderWidth = 3
        }
    }

Answer (score 16):

Setting: 
- **equal widths** of all buttons 
- **horizontal spacing** between all buttons 
- **leading** to superview for the first button and **trailing** to superview for the last button
should do the job. Unless you're having problems with the superview (e.g. ScrollView missing constraints)

Answer (score 7):

In the interface builder you set the spacing constraints between buttons like you described above.  Then you can command-select all of them and specify the "Equal Width" constraint to apply to the selected objects.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I have oblivion how to solve this problem. I've test it works like charm.

1. add constraints to space items with 20 units margin
2. add constraint to ages
3. now tricky part

   - for each item add constraint equal widths to a **parent**
   - select all this new constraints and change its properties
   - set multiplier to value `1:5`
   - set constant to `-24` (6 separation between items and parent edge gives `120`, this multiplied by multiplier value `1:5` gives `24`)
   - update items frames

That's it! Picture below show how it works in interface builder:

[image: interface builder result]

Set simulated size to "freeform" and test different widths (I sett this to `330`).

Answer (score 3):

This problem is seems to be because of wrong `content hugging priority` and `content compression Resistance priority`. So you should set them as low content hugging and high compression resistance (all should have same value).

Because content hugging is the property that resist a view to grow and content compression Resistance priority is to resist a view to shrink. For more information regarding these you can found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried setting the content hugging priority to 250 and the content compression resistance priority to 1000 for both the button and the view but the same occurs.

Comment: By the definitions of `content hugging priority` in the link to the other question you posted, it seems like my problem is related to the hugging. I also tried setting `content hugging priority` to 1 for both the buttons and the views but it's still the same.

Comment: @JianJie friend check out if you are using sizeToFitContent to your buttons?

Comment: No I am not. There is no such property in the IB inspector panel anyway. This problem only came about when I was trying to update my app to use autolayout.