# Extra constraints are logged when I NSLog myBtn.constraints

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have a button inside a view. I have set image for my button in interface builder.
The constraints that I have added to my button in interface builder is:

Right space to superview = 10

top space to superview = 10

bottom space to superview >= 10

left space to a label >= 10

All thing work fine and I have no problem with my layout.
But when I log the button constraints with this code:

```
NSLog(@"constraints for btnBack is: %@", self.btnBack.constraints);
```

the console logs:

```
constraints for btnBack is:(

"<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7c35c400 H:[UIButton:0x7c3588a0(102)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>"

"<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7c35c450 V:[UIButton:0x7c3588a0(92)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>")
```

I know that the top and left and right and bottom constraints shouldn't log here because they are the superview constraints not the button constrains.
But here I didn't add any width and height constrains to my button(even in code).

Why constraints height and width are logged in the console?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a view has a natural width based on its content, it returns that width as `intrinsicContentSize.width`. Otherwise, it sets `intrinsicContentSize.width` to `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`.

Similarly, if it has a natural height, it returns that width as `intrinsicContentSize.height`. Otherwise, it sets `intrinsicContentSize.height` to `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`.

A button has a natural size (both width and height), determined by its title, font, image, and maybe other details. So its `intrinsicContentSize.width` and `intrinsicContentSize.height` are both valid sizes, not `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`.

When `intrinsicContentSize.width != UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`, auto layout installs a special constraint of type `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint` on the view. Similarly, when `intrinsicContentSize.height != UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`, auto layout installs an `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint` on the view.

For the details of what these special constraints do, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32018171/77567).

Comment: So you mean they are like real constraints? I forced my lable width grow, then  I saw my button shrink. (because I didn't add constraint width to my button). If I add constraint width to my button (in interface builder) my button doesn't shrink.

Comment: Yes, they are real constraints, but by default they have a priority less than Required (1000). When you add your width constraint, it has a priority of Required (1000) by default, so it "wins".

Answer (score 1):

If `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `FALSE` then UIKit may add NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint to the view. In that case auto-layout uses `-sizeThatFits:` or `intrinsicContentSize` to compute the view's size.

If you have a view that you are moving from one superview to another, be sure to reset `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. If the new superview uses auto-layout, set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `FALSE`. If the new superview does not use auto-layout, set to `TRUE`. If you fail to reset `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` then you may see unexpected frame animations.