# iOS - How to set constraints such that the bottom of a label will be equal to an image view but the height can vary

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

This how my view looks like:

[image]

I want label 2 to have a fixed 8pts horizontal spacing with label 1 but also having its bottom equal to the image view on the left. Then while having those fixed constraints, the height of label 1 and label 2 may vary as long they maintain close to each other(8 pts of horizontal spacing) and label 2's bottom may be equal or less that the bottom of the image view.

This is what I tried, but it seems like there is a conflict with the constraints:

[image]

Comment: Need more explanation of your fixed and varying constraints for both the labels.

Comment: @SharpkitsInnovations Hi, I just want Label 1's top to be aligned to the top of image view, Label 2 to align with the bottom of imageView, Label 1 and 2 have horizontal constraints of 8 while both of them can vary in heights.

Comment: height of image will be static?

Comment: @Mr.Bista No, height of image will also vary.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because Xcode is confused about which label should compress when there is more content in them and hence show the constraint conflict.

Just increase the Vertical Compression Resistance of your Label 1 greater than that of Label 2.

This will resolve your issue.

If you need detailed explanation on this just visit this link:
[Cocoa Autolayout: content hugging vs content compression resistance priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority)

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question is you want maximum height of your Label1 Plus Label2 should not exceed from imageview's height (still varying the labels height till possible).

Add constraints of your `Label1` as:Leading space to imageview, Align top to `Imageview`, Right space to superview: `Greater than or Equal to` superview, (don't give fix height to any labels)
For `Label2`, Leading space to imageview, Align top to `Label1`, Right space to superview: `Greater than or Equal to` superview,

Now, give bottom space to the Label2 **Greater than or Equal to** the imageview's bottom.

Note: You need to give vertical content hugging content hugging priority of `Label1` to greater than `Label2` (or vice-versa according to your requirement).

[image: Like]