# How to keep view at max width until leading/trailing dimension becomes too small?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I am struggling with autolayout in Interface Builder.

I am having the following layout:

```
-------------------------------
|                             |
|    _____________________    |
|    |                   |    |
|<-->|      UILabel      |<-->|
|    |                   |    |
|    ---------------------    |
|    <------------------->    |
-------------------------------
```

**What I want to accomplish:**
I want the UILabel to have a width of 300, unless the left/right margin becomes less then 30. In that case the UILabel's width must be smaller so the left/right margin will always be 30.

**What I tried:**
UILabel Width: `Less then or equal: 300` 
Left/Right Leading/Trailing: `Greater than or equal: 30`

This works in layouts that don't fit the 360 width, so the UILabel becomes smaller. However, when I have like 400 width available, the UILabel becomes 280 and the Leading/Trailing becomes 50...

I have experimented with different priorities, but nothing seems to have a real effect. I also tried to set the UILabel width constraint to `equal`, but that did not work on widths smaller then 360.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Try setting the leading/trailing constraints simply equal to 30 but set the priority of your width constraint to 750. This way, no matter what the size of the view is, the left and right constraints will be 30.

Comment: look at [hugging priotity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850417/cocoa-autolayout-content-hugging-vs-content-compression-resistance-priority) this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this... on your label:

- set both Leading and Trailing to Greater than or equal: 30
- set Width to 300, with Priority of 999

[image]

[image]

That *should* do what you need.

Comment: Yep I confirm, this is what I would do first. Could you tell us if it worked?

Comment: It didn't work at first, but I removed the label and readded it, and then applied your solution. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Does not work with Xcode 9. Could you please confirm?

Comment: @SRP-Achiever - *"Does not work with Xcode 9"* - you'll need to be a little more descriptive... I just tried it with Xcode 9, Deployment Target iOS 11.0, and it seems to do just what was expected.

Comment: It works because you have centered the view. Try removing the horizontal center constraint and let me know if it works?

Comment: Well, yes, the whole purpose is equal space (min 30-pts) on each side, with the label being max 300-pts in width. If you're trying to do something different, then no, I wouldn't expect this to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Give `UILabel` a width of `300` and set priority to `High`.
Left/Right Leading/Trailing : `30` with `Required` priority.
This should work.