# Why does intrinsicContentSize for UIView always return (-1.0, -1.0)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

A UIView with proper autolayout is not returning a correct intrinsic content size. I am getting (-1.0, -1.0) even though I can see that it is sized correctly both in the storyboard and when the app runs.

I have tried creating a Playground that creates a UIView (a) and a UILabel.
I add my label as a subview of (a) and set left, right, top, bottom constraints.
I also set some text and verified that my label has a correct intrinsic size (which it does).
My (a) view returns (-1.0, -1.0) for intrinsic content size.

I have also tried creating a new project with a storyboard.
I added a UIView (a) to my view and centered it (X and Y).
I added a UILabel to my (a) view and constrained left, right, top, bottom.
I can see that the (a) view sizes correctly. When I run the app I see that it is still properly sized.
My (a) view returns (-1.0, -1.0) for intrinsic content size.

I find this extremely strange considering that the UIView does layout according to its intrinsic content size (i.e. the subviews and associated constraints).

Assuming that my labels constraints to the edges of my (a) view are all distances of 0, then I would expect my (a) view to have an intrinsic content size equal to that of my label's frame (which is based on the intrinsic size of the label, but that is kinda moot).

I genuinely don't understand how a view can set its frame equivalent to the intrinsic size of its subelements while not having an intrinsic content size.

(The frame of (a) view returns the correct size, but that doesn't really answer my question. Also - it isn't helpful for my particular situation, but that is outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: The value `-1` means [UIView.noIntrinsicMetric](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622486-nointrinsicmetric)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I find this extremely strange considering that the UIView does layout according to its intrinsic content size (i.e. the subviews and associated constraints).

This is just a misunderstanding of what the "intrinsic content size" is. An ordinary UIView has no (meaningful) instrinsic content size.

The intrinsic content size is a property that some interface objects implement (such as UILabel and UIButton) so that you do not have give them height and width constraints. These are special interface objects that contain *text* (and/or, in the case of a button, an image), and can size themselves to fit that.

Your UIView isn't like that, and basically doesn't implement the intrinsic content size at all. It is possible to write a UIView subclass that does implement the intrinsic content size, behaving like a UILabel or a UIButton; but you have not done so.

---

You say in a comment:

> If I have a UIView with only a Center X and Center Y constraint and given it has some contents, I would like to know what its size is after autolayout operates

Fine, but that is not its intrinsic content size. It is its *size*. If you are in the view controller, implement `didLayoutSubviews` and look at this view's `bounds.size`. That is the size you are after.

> I'm curious how I could calculate this

Ah, ok. But then you should have asked that. The answer is: call [`systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622624-systemlayoutsizefittingsize).

Comment: If I have a UIView with only a Center X and Center Y constraint and given it has some contents, I would like to know what its size is after autolayout operates.

I figured this would be the "intrinsic content size" because it is the size of an element based upon that which compromises it internally.

Seeing as this seem to be an incorrect assumption, I'm curious how I could calculate this. (I could then override intrinsicContentSize if I want.)

Comment: "and given it has some contents". If it has some contents/subviews (like a UILabel) that have intrinsic content sizes and/or height/width constraints then it is not ambiguous.

I have this clearly illustrated in a sample project. Perhaps I should upload that to Github.

Comment: OK I take back what I said about ambiguity, but my answer is still right: This has nothing to do with intrinsic content size.

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate your clarification regarding the behavior of intrinsicContentSize.

I will give systemLayoutFittingSize a shot and post back with results.

Comment: systemLayoutSizeFitting appears to do exactly what I need.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem! It's interesting and fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS intrinsicContentSize**

[[Content Hugging & Content Compression Resistence Priority]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76046895/4770877)

`intrinsicContentSize` means that view calculates it's size internally (usually in runtime). For example `UILabel` can find out it's size based on text, font, style...

iOS operates by `explicit` and `implicit` constraints. Manually you set `explicit` constrain(in `xib` or in code). AutoLayout converts `intrinsicContentSize` into `implicit` constraint.

For example basic `UIView` doesn't have `intrinsicContentSize`, as an opposite `UILabel`, `UIButton` has it, that is why it is simple to use them with dynamic content. For this reason you must set `width x height` explicitly for `UIView`

`UIImageView` also has `intrinsicContentSize`. When you set image in InterfaceBuilder(image) or programatically(uiImageView.image = image) you see result.